# function is assigned to an Underscores, what is the meaning

Tags: go

In go-plinq(https://github.com/fanliao/go-plinq/blob/master/linq.go), line 28, there is a line listed as above:

```
var _ = fmt.Println //for debugger
```

What is the use of this statement? Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

prevent the `imported and not used` error.

`_` is `Blank identifier`, see [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier)

Comment: Assigning a var to `_` has nothing to do with importing.

Comment: @Flimzy   `var _=fmt.Println` can fix the error caused by `import  "fmt"` but not used. `import _ "fmt"` is the other way.

Comment: No.  `fmt.Println` solves that. Adding `var _ =` in front has absolutely no effect on importing.

Comment: Flimzy, calling fmt.Println() calls the function (in this case, printing a new line character).  Assigning the function to a blank identifier causes the `fmt` package to be imported and "used", but doesn't actually call any functions from it, preventing side-effects but also allowing the `fmt` package to be imported without actually calling anything from it and without triggering a compile error from that lack of use.  It's a way of bypassing the must-by-used restriction on imports in Go.